# Pass Linked Server name as parameter to Stored Procedure (not using Dynamic TSQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to pass linked server name as variable to stored procedure right now after testing and research they all suggest to using dynamic sql and open query which I am using now. however I am not comfortable using it(sql injection) plus I need to call other user defined function to the query. I am looking for a more secure and direct call. Here is my SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBackUpStatus]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@linkedServerName AS VARCHAR(100),
@exemptDB as VARCHAR(100)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.

DECLARE @Sql varchar(8000)
SET NOCOUNT ON;




set @Sql = 'select * from openquery (' + @linkedServerName + ' , ''SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(''''SERVERNAME'''') AS "SERVERNAME",
                                                                          T1.NAME AS DatabaseName, 
                                                                          MAX(T2.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date, 
                                                                          CAST(COALESCE(DATEDIFF(second, MAX(T2.backup_finish_date) , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/ 3600.0, 9999.0) as NUMERIC(6,2)) AS [Hours Since Backup]
                                                                     FROM master.sys.databases T1
                                                                     LEFT OUTER JOIN  msdb.dbo.backupset T2 ON T2.database_name = T1.NAME
                                                                     WHERE T1.NAME NOT IN (''''tempdb'''')
                                                                     GROUP BY T1.NAME
                                                                     ORDER BY T1.NAME'')'

  Exec (@Sql)



END
```

the purpose of this query is to get the server status and its database, I don't like this because of that confusing single quotes, this query will eventually grow as I develop and add function calls.

I tried this and something like this is what I wanted, since it is direct query and cleaner without those quotes. That's how I typically use linked server.

```
Select * from [' + @linkedservername + '].[schema].table
```

thanks

Comment: Dynamic SQL is unavoidable in this case, and this is generally always true whenever you have a statement where the exact shape of the result set cannot be determined in advance by the optimizer. You can cover injection by verifying that `@linkedservername` exists in `sys.servers`, and using `QUOTENAME` consistently. Another option to consider is defining the stored procedure on the remote server and using `EXECUTE AT`, saving you at least one level of indirection.

Comment: Another option (often unfairly overlooked) is simply having the client code (whatever it is) connect to other servers directly, rather than trying to make SQL Server do all the work. It's not intended to be a general remote maintenance tool. You can very quickly execute queries across instances using the registered servers feature of Management Studio, for example.

Comment: Re: `EXECUTE AT`: don't forget that you can replicate stored procedures, so you can still have the master definition at one place (with no dynamic SQL whatsoever) and propagate it to all servers that way.

Comment: thank you @jeroenMostert i'm gonna test that execute at. looks promising..hopefully I can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for a large scale data model with hundreds of tables / objects.
Dynamic modification and cloning of a stored procedure for every linked-server.

It is kinda hiding any dynamic SQL under the hood.

#### How to

Create a stored procedure which interacts with an existing linked-server.

During a database deployment process:

- Obtain the source code of the stored procedure.
- Replace the name of the linked-server in the code.
- If you want to create a new stored procedure (cloned), replace the name of the initial stored procedure in the code.
- Create a cloned stored procedure or modify the current.
- Repeat all steps for each required linked-server.

There are another variations for it.

Now, any external logic may decide which procedure to use.
You can check the existence of a linked-server or its related stored procedure.

For modifications and cloning, it is possible to use SQL Server or external tools, such as C#, CMD, etc.
For [creation under SQL Server](https://github.com/it3xl/linked-server-alias-workaround).